# R combine unique() with logical conditions to subset a data.table

Tags: r, conditional-statements, data.table, unique, subset

I'm using data.table 1.9.6 with R 3.2.1.

I have a data.table with a key called pid.  There are multiple records with the same pid that differ in their level of completeness, the dates the samples were taken on and the type of test performed.  I need to merge this data.table with another data.table on pid, however the second table only has one unique record for each pid.

Before merging, I therefore need to subset the first data.table so that it also contains only one unique record per pid.  I could do this with unique() but this will give me the first record for each pid by order and that isn't necessarily the one I want.  For each pid, I'm looking for the row that contains a particular test type (x), has the earliest sample date for that pid and if more than one with the earliest sample date, then of those the row with the most complete fields as a tie-breaker.

Simply ordering by sample date (min to max) and no. of complete fields (max to min) and then applying unique() gets me part of the way, but efficiently referencing the `test=="x"` condition is where I'm getting stuck.

How can I efficiently de-duplicate the data.table and explicitly select the rows to keep based on them meeting certain logical conditions (which all rows for a given pid can be evaluated on)?

Here is some example data:

```
pid <- c("a1", "b1", "c1", "a1", "c1", "c1", "c1")
sampledate <- c("2014-11-19", "2014-11-01", "2014-11-05", "2014-11-17", "2014-11-05", "2014-11-05", "2014-11-05")
age <- c(10,43,2,10,2,NA,2)
sex <- c("female","female","male","female","male",NA,"male")
test <- c("x", "x", "e", "x", "d", "y", "x")

dt <- data.table(cbind(pid,sampledate,age,sex,test))
dt[, sampledate := as.Date(sampledate)]
dt[, completefields := rowSums(!is.na(dt))]
```

Here is the unique subset using setorder:

```
setkey(dt, pid)
setorder(dt, pid, sampledate, -completefields, na.last=TRUE)
dts=unique(dt)

 > dts
   pid sampledate age    sex test completefields
1:  a1 2014-11-17  10 female    x              5
2:  b1 2014-11-01  43 female    x              5
3:  c1 2014-11-05   2   male    e              5
```

In the above output, for pid "c1" the record for test "e" is selected, whereas I am only interested in the records for test "x".  Including test in the order list will not help me as the options are d,e,x and y with the value I want, "x" falling in the third (if ordered ascending) or second (if ordered descending) position, respectively.

If I add the results of a logical test to my data set I can include the "testisx" column in order and get what I want:

```
dt[, testisx := test=="x"]

setkey(dt, pid)
setorder(dt, pid, sampledate, -testisx, -completefields, na.last=TRUE)
dts=unique(dt)

 > dts
   pid sampledate age    sex test completefields testisx
1:  a1 2014-11-17  10 female    x              5    TRUE
2:  b1 2014-11-01  43 female    x              5    TRUE
3:  c1 2014-11-05   2   male    x              5    TRUE
```

This is fine for small data sets, but creating the extra column for much larger data sets would be computationally expensive.

Is there any way that I could select one row for each pid that meets the conditions as above without creating an extra column?  I don't have to use unique(); I could construct a forloop but before I do that wanted to check if there were any more straightforward methods.

Comment: The same help page `?unique.data.table` describes `duplicated`, which can be used for logical subsetting. I think you're misunderstanding how logical expressions are constructed, though. `max(x)` is a number, not a TRUE/FALSE value; probably you mean to use `x == max(x)`.

Comment: Thanks Frank, the example I selected was probably not the right one as I am interested in logical expressions that can't be ordered (so not max and min but more the testtype=="x" scenario I added at the end).  The syntax in    `dt1 = dt[, .SD[unique(dt) & min(sampledate) & max(completefields)], by=pid]` is probably wrong though (I can create a column that indicates true/false if a particular value of sampledate is equal to the minimum value of sampledate by pid, but I'm still a bit of a novice when it comes to using .SD).

Comment: @Arun: I have updated my question with a clearer example and using setorder, see above.

Comment: Re duplicated; if I understood correctly this function will still mark only the first of each record as not a duplicate.  Thinking it over, I am classifying my problem as a de-duplication issue but accept that unique() and duplicated() were not designed to work in the way I want (although IMO adding optional conditions to de-duplicate on would be a very useful addition).